# Basic arithmetic and division in Natural Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Let k, l, m, n be natural numbers. Prove the following:
If l + m = n, then k divides two of the numbers l, m, n if and only if k divides all three of them.

Note: given natural numbers m, n we say that m divides n, or that m is a divisor of n, notation m|n, if there exists k such that n = km.

Comment: Looks like a nice exercice. Have you tried to solve it ?

Comment: @Evargalo Why would anyone bother doing that when they can just paste it on here and get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The note at the bottom of the question is a heavy hint in how we can prove this.

$k|l => l=ak$, $a$ an integer

If $k|l$ and $k|m$ then $l=ak$ and $m=bk$ so $n= l+m = ak + bk = (a+b)k$ so $k|n$.

Now repeat the above using subtraction to obtain the other results.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $k|l$ and $k|m$ then $k|l+m=n$

If $k|l$ and $k|n$ then $k|n-l=m$

If $k|m$ and $k|n$ then $k|n-m=l$